# Black edges when blending transparent Texture

Tags: c++, c, textures, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to render a Texture with Alpha-Channel to my Window but it shows up with dark/black edges on some parts of the Texture.

The Image is loaded via the SDL_image library `IMG_Load(img_path)` and later
converted to a Texture using `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(img_surface)`.

The Texture has a Alpha-Channel and I would like to blend it onto the Screen.
I use `SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(img_texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND)` to set the Blend-Mode.

The Renderer is created with `SDL_CreateRenderer(m_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);`.

My Problem does not occur when using `SDL_BLENDMODE_ADD` but this mode is not suitable for what I am trying to achieve.

I've also tried:

- to write a custom Blend-Mode that emulates the behavior of the BLEND-Mode, same Problem.
- to change the `SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY` to `"0"`, `"1"` and `"2"` with always the same outcome.

This is an Image of my Problem:
[image: Black edges on Texture]

This is how it should look like:
[image: Now without any black lines]

Why could this happen? I am trying to fix this for hours now and every link on several google-pages is now purple.

The Codebase I am working with is relatively large so I can't copy/paste anything useful,
because of lack of context.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I forgot to mention that this behavior also only appears when
scaling the Image (un-)proportional.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is **example Code** that reproduces my Problem more or less:

```c
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    SDL_Window * win = SDL_CreateWindow("Test Window", 0, 0, 1400, 1000, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer * ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "2");
    
    SDL_Surface * background_surface = IMG_Load("bg2.png");
    SDL_Surface * hitcircle_surface = IMG_Load("hitcircle.png");
    
    SDL_Rect hitcircle_size = {0, 0, hitcircle_surface->w, hitcircle_surface->h};
    
    SDL_Texture * bg_tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, background_surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(background_surface);
    
    SDL_Texture * hitcircle_tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, hitcircle_surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(hitcircle_surface);
    
    SDL_Event event;
    double scalefactor = 1.0;
    
    while(1) {
        
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch(event.type) {
                
                case SDL_KEYDOWN: {
                    scalefactor += 0.01;
                    break;
                }
                
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    exit(1);
            }
        }
        
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(ren);
        
        SDL_Rect hitcircle_size_scaled = hitcircle_size;
        hitcircle_size_scaled.w *= scalefactor;
        hitcircle_size_scaled.h *= scalefactor;
        
        SDL_RenderCopyEx(ren, bg_tex, nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
        SDL_RenderCopyEx(ren, hitcircle_tex, nullptr, &hitcircle_size_scaled, 0, nullptr, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
        
        SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
        SDL_Delay(100);
    }
}
```

**Image for testing:**

[Image i used as "hitcircle"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2DCA.png)

[This is a Bacgkound Image you can use (its not the same Image but it is satisfactory)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fBz6.png)

Comment: What do you mean by black edges? Are you talking about the solid black areas above/below the image or the grayish borders around some of the squares inside the image?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the dark-grayish lines around some of the squares. (I've added another Image of how it should look like for clarification)

Comment: Just a guess ... From: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy I assume you have loops similar to the example code. I think your `SrcR.x` and `SrcR.y` setup is correct. Otherwise, you would have the squares on subsequent lines be staggered diagonally. But, `SrcR.width` and `SrcR.height` setup are [probably] off by one [or so]. (e.g.) You're doing `SrcR.width = 15;` and should be doing `SrcR.width = 16;` [or vice-versa]. Or, the width/height issue _could_ be in `DstR` instead.

Comment: Can you please _edit_ your question and post your equivalent of the example code in a code block here (i.e. about 20 lines or so). Along with the x/y and width/height values you're setting in both the `SrcR` and `DstR` rectangles.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I've edited the question and added reproducing code.